# rudimentary way to check MAC address on linux for licensing

Tags: c, linux, mac-address

**code excerpt:**

```
/* ---------------------------------------------------------------------- */
/* create list mac addresses ofcomputers that program should be allowed to run on */
#define MAX_N_MACS 100

char whitelist_mac[MAX_N_MACS][18];
int nmac = 2;
sprintf(  whitelist_mac[0], "a0:b1:c2:d3:e4:f5" );
sprintf(  whitelist_mac[0], "a0:b1:c2:d3:e4:f6" );

/* ---------------------------------------------------------------------- */

/* how I verify if computer running my code is on my whitelist */

int Check_Licensing ( void )
{
   FILE *fp1;
   char mac_thissystem[18];

   /* lower case found in /sys/class/net/eth0/address */
   fp1 = fopen( "/sys/class/net/eth0/address", "r" );
   if ( fp1 == NULL )
   {
      printf("\n   Error: license problem, program quitting\n\n");
      exit( 0 );
   }
   fgets( mac_thissystem, 18, fp1 );
   fclose( fp1 );

   for ( i = 0; i < nmac; i++ )
   {
      if ( strcmp( ok_mac[i], mac_thissystem ) == 0 )
         return 1;
   }

   /* current system MAC does not match whitelist */
   return 0;
}
```

This works but my issue seems to be portability with trying to reference `/sys/class/net/eth0/address`.  Specify the **eth0** part.  With `biosdevname` and `net.ifnames` on RHEL/CentOS 7 these days being installed there is no guarantee that the path `/sys/class/net/eth0/address` will exist.  The `eth0` can be something else like `eno1`.  I've also seen `enps0...something`.

what is the most reliable and portable way to do something like this on linux?

1. How do I find out the network naming scheme, to first find out if I have `eth0` or `somethingelse` for a network device name?
2. Then, is there a better way to obtaining a network MAC address of a running system, better than using `/sys/class/net/<device_name>/address`?  I'd prefer to not have to require someone to do `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=net.ifnames=0` in order to force `eth0` because of my coding.  I am not interested in making this work in microsoft windows or any other non-linux operating system.

Comment: You could just iterate on /sys/class/net/ contents (or use specialized interfaces, older netdevice(7) or newer rtnetlink(7) ). Of course all this is easily circumvented when a customer creates a virtual interface with a whitelisted MAC address or changes a real interface's mac address.